# Does Zoom always use native resolution for Screen Sharing or is there a limit?

Tags: windows-10, zoom-meeting

My laptop has 3000x2000 resolution and I want to have a Zoom meeting sharing high DPI charts (with small letters). Will Zoom share my screen in the full native resolution? Or is there some limit?

I went through relevant settings but I don't see anything resolution-wise there:

[image]

Then I clicked "Advanced":

[image]

Comment: If the person at the other end only has a regular HD screen, they won't be able to read it anyway. Work to your lowest common denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Zoom help center link](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/207347086-Group-HD) @Tetsujin posted (thanks to him), the Zoom Screen Sharing will always be at the full native resolution:

> **Group HD**
>
> ...
>
> For the time being, standard video, not HD video, will be activated
> when 3 or more participants join a group meeting. HD video (720p) will
> be activated for 2 participants or when a Zoom Room or Conference Room
> Connector joins a group meeting. HD video (1080p) will only be
> activated for selective use cases such as large format broadcast
> events.
>
> ...
>
> **Screen sharing is not affected by Group HD. Screen sharing will
> display content at the native resolution of the desktop, application,
> or portion of the screen being shared.**

So in my case, it should be the full 3000x2000 when sharing full screen.

Comment: Yes and no. You do stream it at 3000x2000, but if the client does not have a resolution this size, it will be scaled down for them to fit, which means that pixels merge together and text will become unreadable.

Comment: @LPChip thanks for important note :)

Comment: You do realize this is exactly what I posted in my answer, right...

Comment: @LPChip not at all. Sorry to say but your answer (".. it will scale it down to whatever resolution they streaming at") didn't bring me any new information. See also the conversation under your answer.

Comment: @LPChip the breakthrough info which I found there is that Zoom is streaming the full native resolution without any downscaling.

Answer (score 2):

You can share your entire screen, in which case it will share the whole 3000x2000 and scale it down to whatever resolution their streaming at, which is usually lower, like 1920x1080 etc.

You can also choose to share one application. If you resize that application to a fraction of your screen, the chance is a lot higher that they will be able to read it.

Another option is to temporarily reduce your own resolution to a lower one.

Comment: *"... to whatever resolution their streaming at, which is usually lower, like 1920x1080 etc."* - this is exactly what I'm asking. What is this resolution, where can I find it, ... I was thinking that perhaps Zoom could share screen at the whole 3000x2000 but at slower rate? Surprisingly I can't find no such info. I need to share the whole screen.

Comment: According to Zoom Help - https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/207347086-Group-HD it streams at either 720 [consumer] or 1080 [enterprise]. No-one is going to let you stream at nearly 4k resolution. Just not going to happen.

Comment: @Tetsujin not true - what about TeamViewer? Thanks for the link!

Comment: Teamviewer & zoom serve entirely different purposes. TV is not trying to stream it as 'live video'. If you do, you'll see it slows to a crawl

Comment: @Tetsujin I am wondering if Zoom applies the same resolution for video/camera and for screen sharing. Because both seem to have different settings.

Comment: @Tetsujin wow, found the answer in the link you posted! Share screen __will__ work at the full native 3000x2000! I've posted it as an answer. Thank you very much for the link! :)